# tikz draw text inside rectangle above bottom border

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am trying to draw a label centered inside a rectangle just above the bottom border and I cannot work out how to place it there using tikz.  Could someone point out how I can place the label at this location

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture,overlay]
\node (rect) [rectangle, draw, minimum width=70mm, minimum height=100mm, anchor= south west] at (0,0) {};
\node (rect.center) {Centered Above Bottom Border};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `label` at `south` of `rect` with an anchor `south`.

```
label={[anchor=south]south:Centered Above Bottom Border}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture,overlay]
\node (rect) [rectangle, draw, minimum width=70mm, minimum height=100mm, anchor= south west,label={[anchor=south]south:Centered Above Bottom Border}] at (0,0) {};
%\node (rect.center) {Centered Above Bottom Border};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you want the label as a separate node, put the node at proper place:

```
\node[anchor=south] at (rect.south) {Centered Above Bottom Border};
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture,overlay]
\node (rect) [rectangle, draw, minimum width=70mm, minimum height=100mm, anchor= south west] at (0,0) {};
\node[anchor=south] at (rect.south) {Centered Above Bottom Border};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why the rectangle has not have a top border?

Answer (score 3):

Don't anchor south west but south, and tell tikz to put your line above the anchor:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture,overlay]
\node (rect) [rectangle, draw, minimum width=70mm, minimum height=100mm, anchor= south] at (0,0) {};
\node [above] (rect.center) {Centered Above Bottom Border};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT** taking @Zarko's comments into consideration

Removed the `[remember picture,overlay]` part since, in the context of this MWE, it distorts the placement of your rectangle on the page

Did away with the anchor altogether since you don't need it if you use your node name properly

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (rect) [rectangle, draw, minimum width=70mm, minimum height=100mm] at (0,0) {};
\node [above] at (rect.south) {Centered Above Bottom Border};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: for your solution doesn't need `[remember picture,overlay]`. settings of `tikzpicture]`. Also names of nodes should't have punctuation  as `.` and `,` ... (imagine, how you will position one more node south of `rect.center`?)

Comment: @Zarko, you are obviously right but it might have been in there for some other purpose of the OP so I just left his code unchanged apart from the immediately necessary edits

Comment: regarding `[remember picture,overlay]` I partially agree with you (since I haven't any information of real use), however I don't see any reason to use  incorrect name for node. On the first sight your solution seems that it for its work require `[remember picture,overlay]`, what is not true.

Comment: @Zarko see edits (even though the OP seems to have abandoned his question...)

Comment: well done!  I vote for your answer  :-).